# Getting find command to show dates in GMT

Tags: linux, date, find

I am running a find command like this

```
  find -name newthing.190618.1.html -type f -printf '%CY-%Cm-%CdT%CH:%CM%CZ|%P\n'
```

and I get a response back like this

```
2019-06-18T13:32PDT|newthing.190618.1.html
```

What I actually want is this date displayed in GMT like this

```
2019-06-18T20:32Z|newthing.190618.1.html
```

Is it possible for "find" to compute and return the date for GMT, as shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporarily set your timezone to UTC:

```sh
TZ=UTC0 find -name newthing.190618.1.html -type f -printf '%CY-%Cm-%CdT%CH:%CM%CZ|%P\n'
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES

Edited following tink's suggestion in the comments.